# How to make devise gem go to specific page when user logs in for the FIRST time using confirmation email link but only in this situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

so i am trying to build a social network for rails practise that using devise gem asks the user to confirm email in order to enable login.

My problem:
I want the user to fill a form when he/she logs in for the very first time.  This first time happens when they click on the link in the confirmation email.

All the other times the user logs in goes to a different page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this feature by overriding the devise confirmation method after_confirmation_path_for.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  private

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    your_new_after_confirmation_path
  end

end
```

add below line in your routes.rb so that devise uses your custom controller.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
```

then restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works.  I also used after_sign_in_path_for(resource) in my ApplicationsController.rb and it worked. So my question is: when do i need to use a custom controller such as the confirmations controller and when not?